# Can I use `beq x1,x0,-2` instead of `beq,x1,x0,label` to avoid multiple definitions of a label?

Tags: assembly, gcc, inline-assembly, riscv

I try to use two same labels in two functions' inline assembly.

```
void fun1(){
    asm volatile(
        ...
        "label:"
        "addi t1,t1,-1\n"
        "bne t1,x0,for\n"
        ...
    );
}

void fun2(){
    asm volatile(
        ...
        "label:"
        "addi t2,t2,-1\n"
        "bne t2,x0,for\n"
        ...
    );
}

void main(){
    fun1();
    fun2();
}
```

But I get a error `symbol label is already defined`.

So I repalce `bne t2,x0,for` with `bne t2,x0,-2`, but my assembler(riscv32-unknown-elf-as 2.39) can't get the correct instruction.

Comment: But why do you use the same name as a label? Is it the result of some macro substitution?

Comment: You can do `.-4` (or whatever the size of an instruction is) but it's not recommended. Instead use a local label, such as `1: addi t2,t2,-1; bne t2,x0,1b`

Comment: @jcmvbkbc: Even if you use different labels, you can have the same problem if your function is inlined in more than one place.  Local labels are indeed the intended solution: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Symbol-Names.html

Comment: Just a reminder, inline asm inside non-`naked` functions needs `: output : input : clobber`, i.e. it has to be GNU C Extended asm to be safe.  If you don't tell the compiler what registers you modify, that's undefined behaviour and will break in hard-to-debug ways.  https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/ConvertBasicAsmToExtended

Comment: @Jester why not make this an answer?

Comment: If you are using Extended asm (as Peter correctly recommends), you can use %= in your [assembler template](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#AssemblerTemplate) to generate unique labels for each instantiation. Your label becomes `label%=:' and you reference it the same way.